# AWS Glue Error: py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89.getCatalogSource. : java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, list, apache-spark, aws-glue

I am running the following glue script to copy certain columns from a postgres table to a bucket in S3.:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame


def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
    for alias, frame in mapping.items():
        frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
    result = spark.sql(query)
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

PostgreSQL_node1668126214499 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="glue-catalog-ra-db",
    table_name="rentalassistance_public_addresses",
    transformation_ctx="PostgreSQL_node1668126214499",
)

SqlQuery0 = """
select id, zip, city from myDataSource

"""
SQLQuery_node1668127298659 = sparkSqlQuery(
    glueContext,
    query=SqlQuery0,
    mapping={"p1": PostgreSQL_node1668126214499},
    transformation_ctx="SQLQuery_node1668127298659",
)

S3bucket_node3 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=SQLQuery_node1668127298659,
    connection_type="s3",
    format="json",
    connection_options={
        "path": "s3://refined-data.edquity-dev.co/demo_data/",
        "partitionKeys": [],
    },
    transformation_ctx="S3bucket_node3",
)

job.commit()
```

Unfortunately, I am seeing the following error in my error logs when I try to run this job:

```
2022-11-11 00:43:45,504 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(73)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/export-public-addresses", line 28, in <module>
    transformation_ctx="PostgreSQL_node1668126214499",
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py", line 787, in from_catalog
    return self._glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(db, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, additional_options, catalog_id, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 186, in create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog
    makeOptions(self._sc, additional_options), catalog_id),
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89.getCatalogSource.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:349)
    at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.$anonfun$getJDBCConf$1(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:218)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.getJDBCConf(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:209)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getGlueNativeJDBCSource(GlueContext.scala:487)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCatalogSource(GlueContext.scala:320)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCatalogSource(GlueContext.scala:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

as well as this in another error log:

```
{
    "Event": "GlueETLJobExceptionEvent",
    "Timestamp": 1668127425524,
    "Failure Reason": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/export-public-addresses\", line 28, in <module>\n    transformation_ctx=\"PostgreSQL_node1668126214499\",\n  File \"/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/dynamicframe.py\", line 787, in from_catalog\n    return self._glue_context.create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog(db, table_name, redshift_tmp_dir, transformation_ctx, push_down_predicate, additional_options, catalog_id, **kwargs)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py\", line 186, in create_dynamic_frame_from_catalog\n    makeOptions(self._sc, additional_options), catalog_id),\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py\", line 1305, in __call__\n    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py\", line 111, in deco\n    return f(*a, **kw)\n  File \"/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py\", line 328, in get_return_value\n    format(target_id, \".\", name), value)\npy4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89.getCatalogSource.\n: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get\n\tat scala.None$.get(Option.scala:349)\n\tat scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.$anonfun$getJDBCConf$1(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:218)\n\tat scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.DataCatalogWrapper.getJDBCConf(DataCatalogWrapper.scala:209)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getGlueNativeJDBCSource(GlueContext.scala:487)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCatalogSource(GlueContext.scala:320)\n\tat com.amazonaws.services.glue.GlueContext.getCatalogSource(GlueContext.scala:185)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\n",
    "Stack Trace": [
        {
            "Declaring Class": "get_return_value",
            "Method Name": "format(target_id, \".\", name), value)",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
            "Line Number": 328
        },
        {
            "Declaring Class": "deco",
            "Method Name": "return f(*a, **kw)",
            "File Name": "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
            "Line Number": 111
        },
...
```

I was wondering if anyone has successfully solved this issue in the past?

Thus far I've tried removing the column selector to try and simplify the overall process to 2 steps but that did not really make a difference.

Additioanlly, I've tried increasing memory/node allocation but neither of these made a difference either.

EDIT: Just tried viewing the data through the "data preview" option on glue's studio's visual editor and I see the same error.  Seems like its clearly unable to locate the data even though the crawler seems to be working correctly as it pulls in the correct tables.

If I'm understanding this right it looks like an issue with locating the catalog database and table.  But I used the visual tool to construct this so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be able to find those crawled tables.

Comment: Any chance you found out why this was happening for you?  I am running into the same issue and I have yet to discover the root cause.   If I do, I will post back.

Comment: In my case, the database was secured with the secrets manager.  While the crawler had no issue with that - the glue ETL job could not use the same db connector.  When I created a db connector using username/password the None.get error went away the job succeeded.

Comment: Same problem. Workaround by P. Ryan worked for me.

Comment: I'm facing the exactly same issue.. did you guys solve it already? In my case I need to use a secret instead of type username/password on the connector config.

Comment: Guys, FYI I found a solution for this issue.. you can set a connection with any string as user/password, and into the job code you can override the user/passord parameters getting it from secrets:

Comment: directJDBCSource(
    glueContext,
    connectionName=...,
    connectionType=...,
    user=get_secret("UserSecret"),
    password=get_secret("PasswordSecret"),
    database=...,
    table=...,
    redshiftTmpDir="",
    transformation_ctx=...,
)

Comment: notice that the parameter name is USER, not USERNAME